# Django test TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ()

Tags: python, django, testing

I got this error 3 times in my code. I searched on other question and I didn't find anything that worked.
Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you.

## models.py

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    semester = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs)
        self.questions = None
```

## test_models.py

```
class ExamModelTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(username='test_user', first_name='Test', last_name='User')
        self.exam = Exam.objects.create(code="EXAM1", name="Exam 1", semester=1, year="2024")

    def test_exam_str_method(self):
        self.assertEqual(str(self.exam), "EXAM1-Exam 1 2024 1")
```

## error

```
Found 12 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.....EEEEEE.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_exam_str_method (examc_app.tests.test_models.ExamModelTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lucile/examreview/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2053, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'tuple'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lucile/examreview/examc_app/tests/test_models.py", line 9, in setUp
    self.exam = Exam.objects.create(code="EXAM1", name="Exam 1", semester=1, year="2024")
  
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ().
```

Comment: please include the code for your `test_exam_str_method` test.

Comment: Include the test itself, not only the `setUp`.

Comment: Also note that the line in the error file does not correspond with the shared `setUp`: `id="1"` is missing...

Comment: ...and that argument seems to be the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], we won't be able to reproduce your problem with the code you have shared. Do you perhaps have a custom `save` method for your `Exam` model?

Comment: Typo: `super().__init__(args, kwargs)` should be `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. If it is not clear why see: [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just insert it this way without going through the id

```
self.exam = Exam.objects.create(id=1, code="EXAM1", name="Exam 1", semester=1, year="2024")
```

or

```
self.exam = Exam.objects.create(code="EXAM1", name="Exam 1", semester=1, year="2024")
```